# How to prevent 'E' when displaying double number in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, html-table, number-formatting

I'm displaying number (of type double in java ) in HTML. And it is automatically converting it to E.

```
<td>${obj.val}</td>
```

when I look at the value in server side/debugger, the value is 13857542.994060002, but it displays the same value in the below format.

```
1.3857542994060002E7
```

I was wondering if there's a way to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to display a fixed number of decimal places, you can use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). For example, this outputs the number with two decimal places:

```
13857542.994060002.toFixed(2); // outputs 13857542.99
```

If you are going to format numbers to locale representation, you can use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
13857542.994060002.toLocaleString('en-US'); // outputs 13,857,542.994
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jstl format

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatNumber type="number" value="${obj.val}" />
```

You could also control the number of decimal places with the attribute

```
maxFractionDigits
```

Comment: I'm using spring form tag to display the phone number and facing the same issue. Phone number showing correctly in DB stored value but when I'm displaying the same in jsp, it's converting to something like 9.2932342E9. Appreciate any help on this.